# jenkins Jmeter Performance report, when http request fails report shows requests highlighted in red, even after request success

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter, report

i have integrated jenkins and jmeter
in the jenkins performance report , when few of the http request failed(throw 500)  ,later the http request are working as expected ,but the report still shows in red for all request
expected is that when http request success, in report they should be displayed in blue.
[image shows detailed last report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EvNE.png)

#jenkinsjmeter #performancereport

i tried to run the report multiple times but color doesn't revert , it says comparison with last run but does not update

Answer (score 0):

Looking into HTTP Code column I can see both [200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) and [503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) there so my expectation is that Jenkins reports the error correctly.

[image]

My expectation is that when you're running your next test you just appending new metrics to the .jtl results file which is in your Jenkins workspace.

You might want to consider using i.e. [Workspace Cleanup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/) plugin.

If you're [running JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) you can also add `-f`  argument to your JMeter execution command so JMeter would delete the existing .jtl results file so you will get the "fresh" results each time.